# What does it mean to say "$C_v$ per atom"?

Tags: thermodynamics, terminology

In the Oxford Solid State Basics second chapter's first footnote, the author says that we should really be saying that for an ideal gas, 
$$C_v \;per\;atom = \frac{3k_B}{2} $$
rather than 
$$C_v = \frac{3k_B}{2}\;per \;atom$$
But why? What's the difference between the two statements?

Comment: In the first, “per atom” means “divided by the number of atoms”. In the second, “per atom” means “for each atom”. This kind of ambiguous language is why, in physics, equations are preferable to words.

Comment: But both will lead to the same conclusion that the total $C_v$ is $\frac{3k_BN}{2}$ right?

Comment: Yes, that’s right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ C_{v} = \frac{3 k_B N}{2}$$ where $N$ is the number of atoms. Divide both sides by $N$ and we have $atom^{-1}$ on the LHS.

Comment: That's it? So saying it the other way round doesn't change the meaning in any way?